# Make sh Commands Stream to Capture Stdin

Tags: shell, stdin, capture

Having `script.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh
sh <<EOF
cat | xargs -n 1 echo captured
echo first
echo second
EOF
```

Running this would output

```
captured echo
captured first
captured echo
captured second
```

So that the second and the third (`echo`) commands were not executed but instead the `cat` just captures and exhausts all the upcoming commands stream and puts down to its pipe

Besides calling

```bash
echo input | script.sh
```

would have the very same effect.

Having the very same three commands as a plain script file `script-plain.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cat | xargs -n 1 echo captured
echo first
echo second
```

would behave differently and

```bash
echo input | script.sh
```

would output

```bash
input
first
second
```

So how to achieve having streaming pipeline e.g.

```
curl some-streaming-endpoint
```

that outputs continuously something like

```
echo ping 1
cat
echo ping 2
echo ping 3
....
echo ping n
```

the behavior of executing them as a plain script and the subject commands to capture the shell stdin it self (if any) instead of commands source one

so that how to make a script `executor.sh` similar to

```
#!/bin/sh
curl some-streaming-endpoint | sh
```

that with the invocation like

```bash
echo "data 1\n$data 2" | ./executor.sh
```

would produce the output

```bash
ping 1
data 1
data 2
ping 2
ping 3
...
ping n
```

P.S. without temporary piping command into a file i.e.

```
curl some-source > ~/tmp/source.sh
~/tmp/source.sh
```

since a stream might be continuous

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. what does desired behaviour look like for your examples?

Comment: what if input contains a shell command that spans multiple lines?

Comment: @jhnc updated the example. If input command exhausts/blocking reads stdin so be it. Just the same flow as the set of command would being invoked  as script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you intend.

If you have bash, perhaps:

```
#!/bin/bash
sh <(curl url)
```

Otherwise, you could make a fifo by hand:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkfifo input
curl url >input &
sh input
wait
rm input
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself

Might be achieved with redirections

`executor.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

4<&0 curl some-streaming-endpoint \
| xargs -L 1 echo '0<&4' \
| sh
```

Still maybe this could be resolved in some simpler way?

Comment: Ah this wont work for multiline commands as if, while, etc